# No search button in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, ios-app

So I've been browsing the app but cannot locate a search button. Am I crazy?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tap on a community's icon to navigate into the question listing
2. Scroll to the top to reveal the search bar (you can also tap the status bar to do this).
3. Profit!

[image: StackExchange iPad app search bar]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Arie. Can I make a request that a search button be added to the left sidebar?

Comment: @toddsby sure, if you'd like to describe the idea in a bit more detail, and maybe a quick mockup, I would suggest opening a separate [tag:feature-request] for that.